# How can I check download statistics for my application?

Tags: application-development

My very first application, Easy Stopwatch, was published about a week ago in Ubuntu Software Center. I'm curious how many people already downloaded it. If I check https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com it says there was no sales so far, but the app has couple reviews, so it's not possible.
[image: statistics for Easy Stopwatch]

I wonder if it's a bug or I can't get stats if app costs $0.

Comment: The software center its self say how may dimes an app has been downloded take a look at your apps page

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see such information there.

Comment: I apologize I thought it did

Comment: No problem. I agree, it should be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is that for now you can't.

Open Source apps at zero cost are distributed through the extras archive at extras.ubuntu.com, and downloads are not tracked from there.

Commercial apps are distributed through private PPAs, which have a reliable method to count downloads and purchases, which are then shown in the graph you're seeing.

So I'm afraid that until there is an implementation for a reliable method of counting downloads from a packaging archive (extras in this case) the download stats will remain disabled for Open Source apps at zero cost.

Comment: Thanks David for explanation, it's not a good news though. BTW, I reported a bug about it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntudeveloperportal/+bug/1039461

Comment: [It apparently works](https://bugs.launchpad.net/developer-portal/+bug/1039461/comments/2). Can you confirm?